# How do I make a regex for this match

Tags: regex, sed

I'm working with this regex and been stuck on this for a while, decided to ask it here:

How do I turn:

`bin -> /system/bin`

To

`/system/bin bin`

using sed.

a.k.a Remove the arrow and bring text after it to front.

I have tried `s/->.*/^/g`, but that does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: And as almost with 90% with sed questions, did you consider `awk`? It might turn out easier for you here, just to split into fields with `->` separator

Comment: Ok. I have tried to `s/->.*/^/g` but that does work. I do not really understand regex that well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how would i do it with awk?

Comment: `awk -F'->' '{print $2" "$1}' file`, or `awk -F'[[:space:]]*->[[:space:]]*' '{print $2" "$1}' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - your comment about "90% of sed questions" got me smiling. Reading on this site, I wonder to the contrary why in 90% of awk answers people don't use sed (or sometimes even grep) instead. OK, 90% is an exaggeration; still, there are more natural ways to crack nuts than with a sledgehammer. The sed solution in your answer seems to me far and away like the most natural for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s/->.*/^/g` command matches the first `->` and the rest of the line and replaces the match with `^`. `g` flag is redundant here.

Since you only have a single `->` in your string, with `awk`, it becomes much simpler:

```
awk -F'->' '{print $2" "$1}' file
awk -F'[[:space:]]*->[[:space:]]*' '{print $2" "$1}' file
```

The `-F'->'` sets the field separator to `->` (`[[:space:]]*->[[:space:]]*` will include any whitespaces before and after it), and you will need to print the two field values in reverse order.

With `sed`, you might consider a solution like

```
sed 's/\(.*\) -> \(.*\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Here, `\(.*\) -> \(.*\)` will match and capture any amount of chars before `->` into Group 1, then `->` will match `->` and the last `\(.*\)` will match and capture any amount of chars into Group 2. The `\2 \1` replacement will swap the two group values.